# Python: function and variable with the same name

Tags: python, function, variables

Why can't I call the function again? Or, how can I make it?

Suppose I have this function:

```
def a(x, y, z):
 if x:
     return y
 else:
     return z
```

and I call it with:

```
print a(3>2, 4, 5)
```

I get 4.

But imagine that I declare a variable with the same name that the function (by mistake):

```
a=2
```

Now, if I try to do:

```
a=a(3>4, 4, 5)
```

or:

```
a(3>4, 4, 5)
```

I will get this error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Is it not possible to assign the variable 'a' to the function?

Comment: well, the error explains itself. You have redefined `a` to be an `int` instead of a `function`; Now, `a` is a variable (instead of a function); hence the consequence

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Are you asking why can't you call a number?

Comment: No, what I just want to know is: if it's possible to after assign "a=2", there is some way to "a" point again to the function.

Comment: While this seems obvious to people who write Python all day, coming from a C# background this is annoying. I may have a 'private' variable named `self.a`, but want to have a 'public' function called `a(units='g')` that converts the units on the private variable 'a' to whatever the caller wants. Instead, I find I need to write my 'public' function as `def format_a(units='g'):`

Comment: Good question, in the end, from the answers, contrary to other languages, you can't have a getter like `def x(self): return self.x`, you need to name the getter differently, e.g. `get_x(self)`. I came here because after a refactoring of my getter name, a working code was just not working anymore.

Comment: @mins you can do that. Its called a `@property` in python. You can do both a getter and a setter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After you do this:

```
a = 2
```

`a` is no longer a *function*, it's just an *integer* (you reassigned it!). So naturally the interpreter will complain if you try to invoke it as if it were a function, because you're doing this:

```
2()
=> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Bottom line: you can't have two things *simultaneously* with the same name, be it a function, an integer, or any other object in Python. Just use a different name.

Comment: Is this behavior due to the fact, that everything is an object in python (integers and functions are both handled as objects?) Or does this hold true to most other programming languages?

Comment: It's true for languages where 1) functions are first-class citizens and 2) types are dynamic; in a statically typed language you cannot reassign say, a number to a variable that was declared to store a function.

Answer (score 8):

**names** in Python are typically `identifiers` for a specific type, more like naming a box which stores a *variable/function/method* or any object in Python. When you are reassigning, you are just renaming a box.

You can find that out by doing the below.

Initially, `a` is assigned a value `9`, at location `140515915925784`.
As soon as I use the same identifier for a function , `a` now refers to a box containing *the address of that function* in `4512942512`

Reassigning `a` to `3` again points `a` to refer to a different address.

```
>>> a = 9
>>> id(a)
140515915925784
>>> def a(x):
...     return x
...
>>> id(a)
4512942512
>>> a
<function a at 0x10cfe09b0>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> a = 3
>>> id(a)
140515915925928
>>> a
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning the name a to a function definition, and then reassigning it to an integer.

It's syntactically correct, but it's not what you want.

It's best to give functions semantic names that describe what you're doing with the arguments being passed to them, and to give variables semantic names that describe what object they're pointing to. If you do that, you'll have more readable code and you certainly won't make this mistake again.