# SQL database not showing enteries

Tags: python, sql

Im trying to develop a simple blog app. With base that for now only has user_name field and text (besedilo). After i run it it shows no errors. But data is not stored in database and does not display later on.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app=Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.form
        user_name = form['user_name']
        besedilo = form['besedilo']
        cur = mysql.connect.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO post(user_name, besedilo) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_name, besedilo))
        mysql.connection.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result_value = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM post")
    if result_value > 0:
        post = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <form method="post">
      NAME:<input type="name" name="user_name">
      BESEDILO:<input type="text" name="besedilo">
      <input type="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block sub_content %}
  <table border = 1>
      {% for post in posts %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{post.user_name}}</td>
          <td>{{post.besedilo}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

db.yaml

```
mysql_host: 'localhost'
mysql_user: 'root'
mysql_password: 'xxxxxxxx'
mysql_db: 'my_blog'
```

What have i missed. I have installed all packages, field names are matching.

```
Database that i set up (with the following commands):
CREATE DATABASE my_blog;
CREATE TABLE post(user_name varchar(30), besedilo varchar(150));

and inserts for fine: with 
INSERT INTO post(user_name, besedilo) VALUES ('Alex', 'i have a job to do');
mysql> SELECT * FROM post;
+-----------+----------------+
| user_name | besedilo       |
+-----------+----------------+
| Peter     | some text      |
| Alex      | i have a job   |
+-----------+----------------+
```

1.) UPDATE :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.form
        user_name = form['user_name']
        besedilo = form['besedilo']
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO post(user_name, besedilo) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_name, besedilo))
        conn.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: No error messages, just no entries. Even if i check my database in terminal

Comment: And you're sure the `INSERT` is executed?

Comment: No. i guess its not if it doest show in database. Because when in terminal i type SELECT * FROM post; there are not entries

Comment: can you edit the question and show the MySQL table that you made?

Comment: There is something suspicious in `cur = mysql.connect.cursor()`. Can you substitute it with `conn=mysql.connect()` and `cur = conn.cursor()` ? And later `mysql.connection.commit()` with `conn.commit()`

Comment: Not related to your problem: there is no excuse for using the potentially unsafe `yaml.load()` with that YAML document.

Comment: Are you sure a variable and method name can be same in Python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161717/python-function-and-variable-with-same-name - i.e. `post` and `post()`. Also `result_value` .. what will `post` be if result_value <=0...  Do you want to do `select count(1) from post` or something like that instead too?

Comment: @AlexYu ok i will try that option

Comment: @AlexYu have i done it correctly : 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])  
def index():
    def request.method == 'POST':
         form = request.form
        user_name = form['user_name']
        besedilo = form['besedilo']
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO post(user_name, besedilo) VALUES(%s, %s)", (user_name, besedilo))
        conn.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')        because now i get error: TypeError: 'Connection' object is not callable

Comment: Excuse me. I was lost in source code between `flask_mysqldb` and [mysqldb](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/blob/master/tests/dbapi20.py). And now I think that problem is much more simple. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have strong suspicion that culprit is `if result_value>0`.

I suppose it's always returns 0 for `SELECT * FROM post` not matter if rows exists in table.

Excerpts from [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-num-rows.html):

> The use of mysql_num_rows() depends on whether you use mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() to return the result set. If you use mysql_store_result(), mysql_num_rows() may be called immediately. If you use mysql_use_result(), mysql_num_rows() **does not return the correct value until all the rows in the result set have been retrieved**.

Try to exclude your `result_value` check and see results:

```
@app.route('/post')
def post():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM post")
    # if result_value > 0: ## I suppose that line always returns 0
    post = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

As for `def index()` - I'm not sure there is a problem there.

Inform about your progress.