# How do I solve this TypeError: 'int' object is not callable?

Tags: python

I try to return number from the function and I got this error:

```
action= action(playerRect, baddies)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

code:

```
action= action(playerRect, baddies)
```

function:

```
def action(p,baddies):
        epsilon = 0.9
        EPS_DECAY = 0.9998
        stats=makestats(p,baddies)
        with open('q.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
                q_table = pickle.load(handle)

        if np.random.random()  > epsilon:
                action=np.argmax(q_table[stats])
        else:
                action = np.random.randint(0, 3)

        epsilon *= EPS_DECAY
        print(action)
        return action
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is probably not your full code, and somewhere before that you assign `action` to an int or running this line in a loop and thus cancelling its binding with the function. Use unique names

Comment: You can't use the same name to refer to two different objects. Use a name other than `action` to store the return value from the function `action`.

Comment: What do you think `action = np.random.randint(0, 3)` is doing to your function name?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse it is not a problem (although not recommended) to use the same name of the function for a variable inside the function (as long as it is not recursive, not the case here). It is a problem to do so outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same name for your variable and function.
Please see the following question: [Python: function and variable with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161717/python-function-and-variable-with-same-name)

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if you got the proper answer to your question.