# How does python disambiguate between module paths and member functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, the dot `.` is used to write paths to modules (e.g. `path.to.mod.func()`) , but also to select member functions (if `x` is of type `T`, `x.func()` is syntactic sugar to `T.func(x)`), as far as I understand it. Let's say I have

```py
# Module which contains a function `sort()`
import mod
# Object of `list` type, which contains `sort()` as a member functin
mod = [3,2,1]

x = mod.sort()  # Now what?
```

What happens in the last line? How does python disambiguate if the dot-separated list of identifiers is: a module/class path to a function, or is (a dot-separated identifier to) an object, then a dot, then a member function from that object's class? I don't know if I'm making myself clear.

This seems to me a bit of an ambiguity in how python parses such an expression. For example, languages such as C++ or rust (and many others) use `::` to separate module paths and `.` to separate object identifiers and member functions / member variables. How come python is able to use `.` for both purposes, unambiguously? What happens in python, and why?

I hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: With `mod = [3, 2, 1]` mod becomes a list and has no association with the imported module whatsoever.

Comment: The method that something resolves to is determined by what the object is when that method is being called. When you call `mod.sort()`, `mod` is a list - so the `sort()` method of the `list` class is called. The import that you did earlier has already been lost at this point.

Comment: After loading the module, `import mod` assigns it to a name just like nay other value gets assigned to a name, with the same rules.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22161717/5987698)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `import mod` you are in practice binding the results of that search to a name in the local scope

```
>>> import numpy 
>>> numpy
<module 'numpy' from 'etc/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
```

With `mod = [3,2,1]` you reassign mod to a list, so now mod is a list

```
>>> numpy = [1,2]
>>> numpy
[1, 2]
```

Thus, with `mod.sort()` you are calling the sort method on a list.
For additional details on the import system you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Answer (score 5):

Outside of the `import` statement, the dot always means "attribute access". Whatever `mod` is bound to, whether it be a module or a list, `mod.sort` refers to the `sort` attribute of the object `mod` references. The assignment to `mod` changes what it refers to, from a `module` object to a `list` object.

There is no separate namespace for modules and and other objects: `mod` can refer to the `module` or the `list`, not both.

The only place a dot is *somewhat* special is in an `import` statement like

```
import foo.bar.baz
```

The purpose of making `import` a statement, rather than a function call, is that the module path doesn't have to be Python expression, meaning the semantics of a dotted path can be unique to the `import` statement. In this case, `foo.bar.baz` is assumed to be a path like `foo/bar/baz.py` or `foo/bar/baz/__init__.py`, relative to a directory in `sys.path`. The choice of syntax anticipates the fact that after this statement execute, the name `foo` will refer to a package module, which will have an attribute `bar` that refers to a subpackage, which will have an attribute `baz` that refers to a module in `foo.bar`.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting. The OP replaced the module `mod` with a plain `list`; the module `mod` doesn't need to have an attribute named `sort`, but the newly bound `list` does. There's no ambiguity because there is only one binding for `mod`.

Comment: Syntactically, it's the same. Maybe the answer is the first `mod` is still just a name referring to an object, the object being a `module` until after `mod` is reassigned.

Comment: Right, but you're kind of on a tangent here. They want to know how Python decides that `mod.sort()` means the `list` method and not the module function. They seem to think `mod` (the module) still exists in some meaningful sense, creating ambiguity, when it does not.

Comment: I think I've fixed the answer to address the actual question.

Comment: That last edit ("There is no separate namespace for modules and and other objects: `mod` can refer to the `module` or the `list`, not both.") answers the question directly. Excellent.