# Python OOP Class Students The error is a1.name type error str not callable

Tags: python

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name ,marks):
        self.name = name
        self.marks = marks
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    def marks(self):
        return self.marks
a1 = Students("Harry",89) 
a1.name()
a1.marks()
```

Comment: a1.name   Type Error: str not callable

Comment: For the next questions, try to provide all the information needed in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` it says when you are calling `a1.name()` name is instance variable of string type which can't be called as method `()`

`name` and `marks` are method name as well as instance variable names. if you change one of them it will work. see below:

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name ,marks):
        self.name = name
        self.marks = marks
    def name1(self):
        return self.name
    def marks1(self):
        return self.marks
a1 = Students("Harry",89) 
n1 = a1.name1()
m1 = a1.marks1()
print(n1,m1)
```

Output:

```
Harry 89
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.name = name` reassigns a string to the name attribute, overwriting the method. Change either the method name or the attribute name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation can be found in this StackOverflow question and answer [function and variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161717/python-function-and-variable-with-the-same-name#:%7E:text=Bottom%20line%3A%20you%20can%27t,Just%20use%20a%20different%20name.&text=names%20in%20Python%20are%20typically,or%20any%20object%20in%20Python.).

> You are assigning the function name and after that reassigning to the variable, that why the error is showing. You have to change either the variable name or function name.

**Sample Code**

```py
class Students:
    def __init__(self, name ,marks):
        self.name = name
        self.marks = marks
    def get_student_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_student_marks(self):
        return self.marks
        
        
a = Students("Naruto Uzumaki", 33) 
n = a.get_student_name()
m = a.get_student_marks()

print(n, m)
```

**Output**

```
Naruto Uzumaki 33
```