# Why did I get an infinite loop (python)?

Tags: python, list, infinite-loop

I'm new to programming.
I'm trying to write a program with 3 lists.
There are no while loops in the code (see below).

I tried saving the user's answers in a list called 'user_answers'.
The for loop is supposed to loop only 5 times (which is the length of the list), but it seems like I got an infinite loop instead.
Any insight on how to fix this?

```py
def user_answer():
     user_answers=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     print('\n')
     for i in range (len(user_answers)):
         print('\nPlease enter the answer to question', i+1, ':', sep=' ', end='')
         user_answers[i]=input()

     return user_answer()
```

Comment: `return user_answer()` is calling the function recursively without any conditional to stop it. In short, your function is calling itself infinitely. It should be `return user_answers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you return that function name `user_answer()` that makes it running recursive indefinitely.

Therefore, you should do `return user_answers` instead of `return user_answer()`.

If you want to make the array having exact size=5, you can loop it 5 times instead of mutating the array every time. You can put the instruction for user input in the `input()` as well. This will make your code more simple. You can try this example:

```
def user_answer():
     user_answers=[]
     for i in range(5):
         user_answers.append(input("Please enter the answer to question "+str(i+1)+": "))
         print()

     return user_answers
     
print(user_answer())
```

P.S. If you want to have 3 lists that each contains 5 elements, you can call the function `user_answer()` 3 times or putting it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create the list before you begin:

```
def user_answer():
     user_answers=[]
     print('\n')
     for i in range(5):
         print('\nPlease enter the answer to question', i+1, ':', sep=' ', end='')
         user_answers.append(input())

     return user_answers
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code return by calling the function, resulting in infinite loop. I guess what you mean is to return the variable user_answers
not to return the function user_answers()

```
 return user_answers
```

This might happen if you confuse function and variables with the same name. You might want to check [function-and-variable-with-the-same-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161717/python-function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're returning the function itself which means you're creating a infinite recursive function.

```
def user_answer():
    user_answers=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    print('\n')
    for i in range (len(user_answers)):
        print('\nPlease enter the answer to question', i+1, ':', sep=' ', end='')
        user_answers[i]=input()

    return user_answers

print(user_answer())
```

Try changing `return user_answer()` line to `return user_answers`

 I hope you're trying to return the user answers array for further work.