# local variable 'subprocess' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, sys, telebot

Here is it my code, I'm trying to perform command in commandline and get output, but I got error. Please help me

```
import telebot
import subprocess


token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['echo'])
def changeWall(message, res=True):
    subprocess = subprocess.Popen("echo Hello World", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess_return = subprocess.stdout.read()
    print(subprocess_return)
    bot.reply_to(message, subprocess_return)
```

Error:

```
local variable 'subprocess' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Might be related to your variable name, you have override the reference to the `subprocess` module. Try renaming your variable (first line in your function). Also, please include the full traceback of your exception, we can't know which line caused the error

Comment: change the variable `subprocess` to any other name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the name of the `subprocess` variable.

You can read more here: [Python: function and variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161717/python-function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

Also I recommend that you remove the token from the code.

Comment: Thanks bro, I forgot about token ahahah